# QuickBooks custom application deployment

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I have created an application in c# that connects to our QB in order to post invoice ans such.  I am ready to deploy this to out accountants so they can further test the application.  This app works fine on my machine, however, when I build my project and take the exe to one of our accountants computers I get an error about  "COM class factory, blah, blah Class not registered"

In the past that error would mean that I need to build the c# with x86 and not x64, but I did and still receive the error.  I now believe that they do not have the QBFC12.dll registered on their computer like I do.

Is this the problem, and if so then do I have to manually register the dll or is their another way to get that dll on their machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer finally.

1. If you installed QBSDK, explore that folder and locate the Tools folder
2. Under that you should find a Installers folder that has "QBFC12_0Installer.exe"
3. Install the exe on the client machine.
4. Try to run your program, if you encounter another error about "QBXML components are not installed, you will need to re-install QuickBooks and follow from step 1 again.  This should get your application up and running for the client.

The person that came the closest and set me on the right track was MikeBr59 so I upvoted him, and posted this incase it helps anyone else.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to copy it manually and register.

There is no other alternative.

Follow the below steps to copy and register it manually.

**1.copy "QBFC12.dll" file into following 2 folders :**

a.C:\Windows\System32\

b.C:\Windows\SysWOW64\

**2.register the "QBFC12.dll" file using following steps :**

open Command Prompt

```
cd C:\Windows\System32
regsvr32  QBFC12.dll
```

**3.while running the project from visual studio force the platform target as 32 bit -> as the project hasbeen developed in 32 bit using following steps:**

```
Right click on Project
Select Properties
Goto Build Options
Change  "Platform Target" from "ANY CPU" to "X86"
```

**4.now run the Project.**

Comment: Thanks, however when I follow your instructions and try to register the dll I get a regsvr32.exe error "Unable to load, may not be compatiable with windows 32 bit or 64 bit machines"

Comment: Why would you not just run the QBFC installer that comes with the SDK?

Comment: @Rechard : get a valid dll file.

Comment: MikeBr59, I was not aware of a QBFC Installer.  Where would that be located and would you happen to know how I would use it?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [QuickBooks SDK docs](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/go-live/redistributing-sdk-components-with-your-application)

> You can never redistribute the request processor DLL (qbxmlrp.dll or qbxmlrp2.dll). This violates the license agreement and can lead to undesirable user experiences.

> NOTE: It is a violation of your qbXML license agreement to redistribute QBFC, RDS, the QBO connector, or the web connector without using either our stand-alone installers or our merge modules.

To solve this problem, I created the following static class:

```
public static class QbfcInstaller
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Installs QBFC if not registered
    /// </summary>
    public static void install()
    {
        bool installed = CheckIfInstalled();
        if(!installed)
        {
            string path = @"\\192.168.1.4\App\Publish\QBFC15_0Installer.exe";
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            //This is required in order for the Process to be able to request Elevation
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            startInfo.FileName = path;
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            //This is required in order for the Process to request Elevation
            startInfo.Verb = "runas";
            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show("In order to work properly the application needs to install the Quickbooks Connector Library.\nPlease DO NOT skip this step or it will cause errors latter."
                    , "Install QBFC 15.0", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                using(Process installProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
                {
                    installProcess.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to install QBFC Error: " + ex.Message);
                Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if QBFC is registered
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static bool CheckIfInstalled()
    {
        try
        {
            IQBSessionManager sessionManager = new QBSessionManager();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            if(ex.HResult == -2147221164)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then, I modified `Program.Main()` to call `QbfcInstaller.install()` before starting the `Application`:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        QbfcInstaller.install();
        Application.Run(new FrmLogin());
    }
```

This basically checks if QBFC COM is registered by trying to create a `QBSessionMenager`. If an error occurs, it checks if `ex.Hresult` is `-2147221164`, which is the error that throws if it's not registered. If it's not registered, it then starts the QBFC installer from a local shared folder. (You can also download the installer from a web server and then run it.)

Comment: Technically you can also do this by creating a custom Bootstrapper(prerequisite) See Microsoft's sample [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-bootstrapper-to-show-a-privacy-prompt?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp), but this will only work on new installs and will not install during an update (if you are using Click once Deployment)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue of my x64 application not being able to use `QBFC12.dll` over COM by creating a COM+ application and registering `QBFC12.dll` as components of that COM+ application in Windows Component Services.